# Failed to load GLFW3 shared library on Windows

Tags: python, windows, dll, glfw

I am trying to run python code which imports GLFW3 library. It gives this error:

> ''' File ".\run_simulation.py", line 15, in 
>       from modules.graphics.simulator_visualizer import SimulatorVisualizer   File
>   "F:\webapp\p1_aksu_rubius\utils..\modules\graphics\simulator_visualizer.py",
>   line 2, in 
>       import glfw   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\glfw__init__.py",
>   line 34, in < module>
>       raise ImportError("Failed to load GLFW3 shared library.") ImportError: Failed to load GLFW3 shared library. '''

I use Windows Server 2012 R2 and Python version 3.7.4 (64 bit)

I found that there is **glfw3.dll** file in the directory `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\glfw`. Then I add this path into Windows environment variable - PATH. Anyway is does not help. What is the problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the *.dll* is there (it's in the right place), then it was found. Adding its path to *%PATH%* won't do anything. 
It's one (at least) of its dependencies that's missing.

According to [[PyPI]: GLFW](https://pypi.org/project/glfw):

> Windows
>
> The GLFW shared library is included in the Python wheels for Windows, but the correct Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable will be required:
>
> - [VC 2010](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555) for 32-bit Python, or
> - [VC 2012](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679) for 64-bit Python.

So, you need [[MS]: Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4 (x64)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679). Select **VSU_4\vcredist_x64.exe**, download, install it and try again.

Let me know how it works out.